# pandas ix. I can not assign values selecting through ix

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_variable = pd.DataFrame(columns=variable)
df_variable.loc[0] = pd.Series()

df_variable.loc[0,'userid'] = 1

df_variable['userid'].ix[0] = userid

print(userid)
print(df_variable['userid'].ix[0])
```

I have trouble about above code. the value of df_variable['userid'].ix[0] is 1, however, userid is 1524343. Can someone give me some suggestion

Comment: Can I ask you, how you came across using `.ix`? It is ambiguous by design and has subsequently deprecated so you should not be using it.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. For example, is `f_variable` actually `df_variable`? What are `variable` and `i`?

Comment: it's my faulty,i have put right it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to set the first value of the column `userid` to `userid`. To do this, you can use the integer location indexer `.iloc` but first find the location of the column `userid`

```
col_num = df.columns.get_loc('userid')
df_variable.iloc[0, col_num] = usreid
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The above code is a part of long code which has thousands of rows. In the long code, lots of  statement 
 similiar with 'df_variable['userid'].ix[0] = userid' were used. It worked util some days ago. But it can not work now. Why did this happen? In the same computer, I create new file and run above code. It can work. why?

Comment: There is no way to know this without seeing your code. But you should certainly think about removing .ix.